# too many redirects. setting up htaccess to redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I moved an old website to a new cms and some content have links that cannot be found on the new system.

For instance in the old system there was a link called https://example.com/newsletter/1234/123
in the new one i do not require those ids at the end. Therefore I would like to redirect the user to
https://example.com/newsletter/ directly.

I wrote the following in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule  ^(.*newsletter)(.*) $1 [L,R=301]
```

This gives me unfortnately a "too man redirects" error.
Can anyone point out the error that I made?

I planned to use the regex to capture all links that contain the name "newsletter" and remove the rest of the url to redirect the user. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `(.*newsletter)(.*)` causes the rewrite to match `/newsletter` alone because `.*` matches zero or more characters. This sends mod_rewrite into a loop.

Instead, you can use `.+` which matches *one* or more characters, and to that I would prepend `/?` to optionally match a trailing slash. There is no need to capture it in `()` because you do not reuse it as `$2`.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*newsletter)/?.+ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Your example began with `.*`. If you actually need that, leave it in. But if you are really just trying to match `/newsletter/123/1234` and not `/someother/newsletter/123/1234`, simplify it with:

```
RewriteRule ^newsletter/?.+ /newsletter [L,R=301]
```

When you test this, use a private/incognito browsing window or a fresh browser. Browsers aggressively cache 301 redirects and it can make it very hard to debug rewrite rules if you are fighting against the cache.

Comment: thanks you sir helped me out. Now I also understand the behaviour. Will learn from this.